# G++ ignoring private access

Tags: c++, g++

I have the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
    int a;
} foo;

int main()
{
    foo.a = 42;
    std::cout << foo.a;
}
```

It outputs "42" but it shouldn't, as `a` is clearly private as class members are private by default. I have G++ 5.3.1 is this a bug?

Comment: Can't replicate with the same compiler. This can't be the code you are actually trying to build. Did you by mistake use `struct` in your actual code?

Comment: Same - sure you didn't accidentally put `struct` ?

Comment: [Does work in g++ 5.3.0](https://godbolt.org/g/vGHfTQ). Please confirm you  posted the exact code you compiled , and the compiler is actually compiling the code you think it is , and also show the compiler commandline